# Ignore forlder in gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to write a watch task with gulp to watch my server php files. But I won't watch the whole vendor dir. For now my code looks like this:

```
var paths = {
    src: [
        'src/**/*.html',
        'src/**/*.js',
        'src/**/*.css',
        'src/server/**/*',
        'src/server/**/.*'

    ],
    dist: 'dist',
    base: 'src',
    watchSrc: [
        'src/**/*.html',
        'src/**/*.css',
        '!src/server/vendor/**/*',
        'src/server/**/*.php',
        'src/server/**/.*'

    ]
};

gulp.task('copy:src', function() {
    gulp.src('node_modules').pipe(symlink(paths.dist + '/node_modules', {force: true}));
    gulp.src('src/server/vendor').pipe(symlink(paths.dist + '/server/vendor', {force: true}));
    return gulp.src(paths.src, {base: paths.base}).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function(cb) {
    rimraf(paths.dist, cb);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    runSequence('clean:dist', 'copy:src');
    return watch(paths.src, {verbose: true, base: paths.base}).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});
```

But this does't work for me. Maybe you have an idea how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've got it there is an copy and paste error which calls the watch task with the wrong path:

IS:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    runSequence('clean:dist', 'copy:src');
    return watch(paths.src, {verbose: true, base: paths.base}).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});
```

CHANGED TO:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
        runSequence('clean:dist', 'copy:src');
        return watch(paths.watchSrc, {verbose: true, base: paths.base}).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
    });
```

Now it seems to work